# how to add map into foreach of Java stream

Tags: java, filter, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I previously wrote following:

```
          events.stream()
                .map(d -> cli.getItem(d.getValue()))
                .map(event -> Report.builder()
                        .id(event.getId())
                        .value(event.getValue())
                        .build())
                .filter(r -> !excludesSet.contains(r.value))
                .forEach(r -> {
                    System.out.println(String.format(r.value);
                });
```

`getItem` returns `Item` here, I just updated `getItem` to `getItems`, which returns `List<Item>`, and want to keep some logic for every item. Which means I need to create a `foreach` and put original map, filter and forEach method in it under  `.map(d -> cli.getItem(d.getValue()))`, how could I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What’s the point of `System.out.println(String.format(r.value))`? First, `println(String.format(…))` can be replaced by `printf(…)`, second, if you don’t have any arguments to format, you can use a plain `println(r.value)` without calling for an expensive formatting framework.

Comment: That's something else actually, I have some other method calls and things there, but don't want to distract people. But good point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a use case for [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

```
events.stream()
    .flatMap(d -> cli.getItems(d.getValue()).stream())
    // everything below stays the same
```

`flatMap` allows you to map each item in a stream to multiple items.